# MYSQL Update based on a JOIN query

Tags: mysql

Hey I am trying to run the following UPDATE in MySQL based on a select but it is very slow

```
UPDATE base JOIN data 
ON base.pk_col_1 = data.pk_col_1 AND base.pk_col_2 = data.pk_col_2 
SET base.base_col_1 = data.value_col_1 
WHERE data.col_x = 'a' AND data.col_y = 'b' AND data.col_z = 'c' AND data.pk_col_1 = n;
```

pk_col_1 and pk_col_2 are primary key columns in both base and data tables.

The select is quick and when I run an explain on the update I see the indexes being used. Any way i can speed up these update queries?

Comment: You may need another index based on col_x, col_y, col_z and pk_col_1, so the where clause can be executed with that index.

Comment: I do have those indexes. The explain even shows they are being used..